# Facebook page plugin using iframe not showing up on page

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am trying to integrate my Facebook events page onto my website using iframe

I have used the following code:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fwarwicktech&tabs=events&width=340&height=410&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=true&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="410" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

I am very confused as for the majority of the time the events page does not show up on the site and sometimes it shows up but in a strange format. Im happy to share the repo for the code if it is a formatting error

Comment: it worked corrrecly when i add a stack snippet :)

Comment: Works fine for me in a jsfiddle, too. Doesn’t look like anything is wrong there; might rather be a local issue on your end. Check if the browser console has anything to say that might be related.

Comment: @04FS  Yes I think it was a local issue. When I restarted the local page it worked :)